# Factory method returning an concrete instantiation of a C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, factory

I have a class

```
template <unsigned int N>
class StaticVector {
// stuff
};
```

How can I declare and define in this class a static factory method returning a StaticVector<3> object, sth like

```
StaticVector<3> create3dVec(double x1, double x2, double x2);
```

?

Comment: You have to replace public by class in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How can I declare and define in this class"

In what class? You've defined a class template, not a class. You can't call a static function of a class template itself, you have to call a particular version of the static function that's part of a real class.

So, do you want the template (and hence all instantiations of it) to have a function returning a StaticVector<3>, or do you want one particular instantiation of that template to have a function returning a StaticVector<3>?

If the former:

```
  template <unsigned int N>
  struct SV {
    int contents[N];
    static SV<3> get3dVec(int x, int y, int z) {
      SV<3> v;
      v.contents[0] = x;
      v.contents[1] = y;
      v.contents[2] = z;
      return v;
    }
  };

  int main() {
    SV<3> v = SV<1>::get3dVec(1,2,3);
  }
```

works for me.

If the latter (you only want get3dVec to be a member of SV<3>, not of all SV<whatever>), then you want template specialisation:

```
  template <unsigned int N>
  struct SV {
    int contents[N];
  };

  template<>
  struct SV<3> {
    int contents[3]; // must be re-declared in the specialization
    static SV<3> get3dVec(int x, int y, int z) {
      SV<3> v;
      v.contents[0] = x;
      v.contents[1] = y;
      v.contents[2] = z;
      return v;
    }
  };

  int main() {
    SV<3> v = SV<1>::get3dVec(1,2,3); // compile error
    SV<3> v = SV<3>::get3dVec(1,2,3); // OK
  }
```

If for no other reason than to make the calling code look nicer by omitting the basically irrelevant template parameter, I agree with Iraimbilanja that normally a free function (in a namespace if you're writing for re-use) would make more sense for this example.

C++ templates mean that you don't need static functions as much in C++ as you do in Java: if you want a "foo" function that does one thing for class Bar and another thing for class Baz, you can declare it as a function template with a template parameter that can be Bar or Baz (and which may or may not be inferred from function parameters), rather than making it a static function on each class. But if you do want it to be a static function, then you have to call it using a specific class, not just a template name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
template< unsigned int SIZE >
StaticVector< SIZE > createVec( const std::tr1::array< double, SIZE >& values )
{ 
     StaticVector< SIZE > vector;
     for( int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i ) // here assuming that StaticVector have [] operator to access values on write
     {
         vector[i] = values[i];
     }

     return vector;
}
```

... or a variant would certainly work. (did'nt test it)

Usage would be:

```
std::tr1::array< double, 3 > vectorValues = { 10.0, 10.0, 42.0 };

StaticVector<3> vector1 = createVector( vectorValues ); // if the compiler can guess the size from the array information
StaticVector<3> vector2 = createVector<3>( vectorValues ); // if you have to specify the size
```

An alternative would be to replace std::tr1::array by a basic array but it would be using raw arrays at your own risks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, i believe you originally mean to return

```
StaticVector<N>
```

Instead of always a specialization with N==3 . So, what you want to do is writing it like this:

```
template <unsigned int N>
class StaticVector {
public:
    // because of the injected class-name, we can refer to us using
    // StaticVector . That is, we don't need to name all template
    // parameters like StaticVector<N>.
    static StaticVector create3dVec(double x1, double x2, double x2) {
        // create a new, empty, StaticVector
        return StaticVector();
    }

};
```

If you really want to always return a 3dVector, you would probably want to restrict it to N==3, so that for example `StaticVector<4>::create3dVec` doesn't work. You can do that using the technique described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347096/how-can-i-get-a-specialized-template-to-use-the-unspecialized-version-of-a-member/347107#347107).

If you want to have a function like `createVec` that works with any size, you probably want to replace the parameters with an array. You can do otherwise, but that's advanced and requires some macro tricks applied with boost::preprocessor. It's not worth it i think. The next C++ version will provide *variadic templates* for this purpose. Anyway,consider using something like this:

I think it would only complicate this unnecessarily here. A quick solution is to use a boost::fusion::vector instead, putting it into the class template instead of the version above:

```
static StaticVector createVec(double (&values)[N]) {
    // create a new, empty, StaticVector, initializing it
    // with the given array of N values.
    return StaticVector();
}
```

You could use it with

```
double values[3] = {1, 2, 3};
StaticVector<3> v = StaticVector<3>::createVec(values);
```

Note that it accepts an array by reference. You can't give it a pointer. That is because it matches the use of parameters: You couldn't provide less or more arguments for the other way too. It will also protect you from cases like this:

```
// oops, values is a null pointer!
StaticVector<3> v = StaticVector<3>::createVec(values);
```

An array never can be a null pointer. Of course if you like, you can always change the array parameter to a pointer. It would just be my personal preference :)

Answer (score 0):

@litb

I wanted to return a 3-element vector. The reason is that these vectors are supposed to be geometric entities, so there is no need for N to be too high (I'm not a string physicist, so I don't work in 11-dimensional spaces). I wanted to create a template to avoid duplicating code but keep 1-, 2- and 3-dimensional vectors as separate types.

Comment: If certain dimensions are special cases, you might find it helpful to do either "typedef StaticVector<3> Vec3;" or "class Vec3 : public StaticVector<3> {". The former just reminds you it's special. The latter lets you define "special" properties of Vec3 but leave StaticVector<3> alone just in case.

Comment: ... just in case you ever actually want a StaticVector<3> that doesn't have the special-case behaviour, I mean.