# What does the :: operator do in this situation

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods, template-meta-programming

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
  static const int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value;
};

// Base case via template specialization:

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
  static const int value = 1;
};
```

So I might have figured out that here the role of the '::' operator is to somehow feed/add into the 'value' variable the content of the operation performed earlier (N * Factorial). But can someone explain this in a more thorough manner (I wouldn't mind a full explanation of the '::' operator roles).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The `::` operator does the same thing in all cases.  It access the name on the right from inside the name on the left.

Comment: `::` is a [scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082113/calculating-factorial-using-template-meta-programming It explains what is happening here, not exactly what :: is

Comment: @NathanOliver code is same question is different, so not a dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver and Marek R, I actually find that other thread useful, as I am still trying to wrap my head around the backtracking this algorithm implies (not the actual algorithm, but the way in which the 'value' variable is being instantiated and updated). Cheers!

Comment: You should grab a copy of C++ templates and learn how template meta-programming works. This is a fairly basic example to illustrate the power of C++ templates. Btw, `::` does not need templates to work.

Comment: @Tanveer Badar Do you have any suggestion? I am currently geared towards cppreference.com and Bjarne Stroustup' Programming Principles and Practice 4th edition where he does speak a bit about templates.

Comment: I also see that in 'A Tour of C++' (by Bjarne Stroustup) the 6th chapter goes in depth about Templates. I'll also check that out

Comment: cppreference.com is just that, a reference - though a very good and nearly complete one. C++ templates is a great book for metaprogramming, though I must admit I haven't read it in any detail yet. The C++ programming language is also good, whatever edition you can get but prefer 4th edition if you can. MSDN's C++ reference and language sections are good source, but whatever you code write after reading that, be sure to run it through GCC/Clang too to root out any MSVC specific stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I might have figured out that

I strongly suggest *learning* C++ from a book, and learning to use existing reference material, rather than trying to figure out what some code means from first principles. You're very likely to make subtle mistakes if you go by educated guesses.

The expression `Factorial<N - 1>::value` is a [qualified identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers).

`Factorial<N - 1>` is the name of a class (an instantiation of the `Factorial<int>` template with a specific value for the single parameter). This class has a data member called `value`. Explicit qualification is needed since this *particular* `value` isn't otherwise in scope. See also [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup).

You can use `::` like this for any class member: for example `std::string::npos` roughly means *find the data member called `npos` in the class called `string` in the namespace called `std`*.

> ... somehow feed/add into the 'value' variable the content of the operation performed earlier ...

there is no "earlier", this all happens during the same stage of compilation.

For example, I can manually write

```
struct F_0 { static const int value = 1; }
struct F_1 { static const int value = 1 * F_0::value; }
struct F_2 { static const int value = 2 * F_1::value; }
struct F_3 { static const int value = 3 * F_2::value; }
```

etc. etc. for as many values as I want. The templated version is effectively the same but saves a lot of typing.

Specifically, writing `Factorial<3>` *instantiates* the template `Factorial<int N>` for `N=3`, which means we now have a concrete non-template class `Factorial<3>` equivalent to the `F_3` I wrote manually above.

The definition of this class refers to `Factorial<N-1>::value` (with `N-1 = 2`), so `Factorial<2>` gets instantiated too. This chain of implicit instantiations continues until we reach the explicitly specialized `Factorial<0>` (without that, it'd keep trying to instantiate `Factorial<-1>`, `Factorial<-2>`, forever until the compiler gave up and failed).

Comment: I agree that there is still much I need to learn and I also want to thank you for the competent reply.

Comment: Also, by 'earlier' I meant it as in written before in the code; I didn't want it to be interpreted as in a measure of time passed.

Answer (score 6):

The `::` operator is called the scope resolution operator. It "resolves," or makes clear, the scope in which the right-hand operand, a variable name, is located.

For example, `std::cout` makes it clear to the compiler that the identifier `cout` should be searched for in the namespace `std`. In your case, the `Factorial<N - 1>::value` makes it clear that `value` is a member of the templated class `Factorial<N - 1>`. It's used here because `value` is a `static` field of the class.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class `foo` with a static member `bar`, then you can [refer to it with the `::` notation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) as `foo::bar`.

Here, `Factorial<N - 1>` is a class, with a static member `value`. Asides from the template notation, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

`struct Factorial` template class resolves `value` from `struct Factorial<N - 1>` and each time the `value` is resolves recursively. And at the end the `value` will be `1` from the following base case :

```
template <>
struct Factorial<0>
```

the `value` determine here :

```
Factorial<5> f;
std::cout << f.value << std::endl;
```

So, the output will be : `120`

Comment: Not incorrect anymore. Let me retract my previous comments.

Comment: please don't automatically approve *bad* edit that turns code into snippet like you did here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23586198 .. the OP is using a SASS code and it's very bad for the question to make it a snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
static const int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value
```

It means that the value of the member `Factorial<N>::value` is `N` multiplied by the value of the member `Factorial<N-1>::value`. (Except for `Factorial<0>::value`, which is specialised to provide a recursive *base case*)

Both `Factorial<N>` and `Factorial<N-1>` are classes.

`::` is the scope resolution operator and tells the compiler that you want to access a member (in this case, a `static` member) of the class (or namespace) to the left of it.

A simpler example:

```
class Foo
{
    static int x;
};

int Foo::x = 42;

int main()
{
   int y = Foo::x;  // access the member 'x' in the class 'Foo'
}
```

or:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "hi!\n";  // access the object 'cout' in the namespace 'std'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more clear consider an alternative access to the data member `value`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial {
  static const int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>().value;
};

// Base case via template specialization:

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
  static const int value = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Factorial<12>().value << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
479001600
```

Here is used the member access expression `Factorial<N - 1>().value` or `Factorial<12>().value`.

So to specify an access to the data member `value` (and especially for non-static data members) you create an object of the type `Factorial<N - 1>` or Factorial<12>.

But static data members do not require an object of the class to be created. So it is much simpler and safer to use a class name and the operator :: to specify an access to a static data member.

The member access expression `Factorial<N - 1>::value` specifies that `value` is a static data member of the class `Factorial<N - 1>`. Neither object of the class `Factorial<N - 1>` is required. It is enough to specify the name of the class to which the static data member belongs.

Answer (score -3):

The '::-operator' is used to access things in namespaces (std::string) or static things in a class:

```
struct C {
    static int i = 42;
};
int main() {
    std::cout << C::i << '\n';
}
```

Here C::i is static, so I don't need an instance of class C. To access some non-static thing inside a class you use a '.'. In your example Factorial is no class but a template, Factorial is a class and Factorial::value is the static int value inside the class Factorial.

Comment: a `namespace` in C++ is a distinct concept. You mean to say scope there, as basic_string defines a class, which is a scope not a namespace.