# Non-Type parameters for templates

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does template <unsigned int N> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499106/what-does-template-unsigned-int-n-mean)

Hi ! Are non-type template parameters and constants same ? Do the following code work because template parameter cannot be modified ? If can be modified, the compiler should have thrown error while declaring array "a[T]". Is my understanding correct ?

```
template < int T > 
void foo() {  
  int a[T] ;  
}  

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {  
  foo <3> () ;  
  system("pause") ;  
  return 0 ;  
}
```

Comment: @ybungalobill Thanks for editing the code part.The way I did was - started with <pre><code> tag and ended with <pre></code>. And for each end of line, I have given 1 space. While in preview, it shows correctly. But after posting, it is changing? It would be helpful for further posts if you can say me the way you edited ?

Comment: @marcog The link was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @marcog: I agree. Especially Johannes' answer is very exhaustive.

Comment: You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35794e13-1e4d-45f4-9206-71505d9aa94d/view-source). You begin each line of the code with 4 spaces, or just use the code button on the toolbar: {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, kind of. Thing is every time you instantiate a template the compiler will generate specific code for that specific type parametrization. So for instance, in your example if you have `foo<3>` and `foo<5>` the compiler will generate code for two separate functions one where `T=3` and one where `T=5`

So yeah, it works because `T` can't change, the mechanism why it works is slightly more complex though...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, non-template parameters have to be constant expressions.