# How to write a template function that takes an array and an int specifying array size

Tags: c++, arrays, function, template-function

For a university exercise, I  have been asked to write a template function "print();", which takes two arguments, 1: an array of a generic type, and 2: an int specifying the size of the array. The function should then print out every item in the array to the console. I am having some trouble with the function arguments. The code I currently have is:

```
   template <typename Type>
   Type print (Type a, Type b)
    {
        Type items;
        Type array;
        a = array;
        b = items;

        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "The element of the index " << i << " is " << array << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

and in main():

```
    print(Array[], 10);
```

Obviously putting Array as an argument isn't returning a value, so I am not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it fine to pass a pointer (after array-to-pointer decay) or do you want to take the array by reference?

Comment: (in the first case you could then also pass non-static arrays)

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure, I have only written in this question exactly what the text book has asked me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The ***correct*** way to write it is

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40899ffa68ac58d2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t size> void print(const T (&array)[size])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,99};

    print(arr);
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3 4 99
```

Comment: Thank you, what exactly would I put in as an argument when I call the function in main? If you could give me a quick example that would be great, I'm new to c++!

Comment: Needs more range-for. Boost.Range `indexed` if indices are needed ;)

Comment: @willfo added a live sample

Comment: Why can't we pass the array by value?

Comment: @Nathan29006781 that's how the language is defined - [it _decays_ to a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#:~:text=of%20array%20type-,Array%2Dto%2Dpointer%20decay,-There%20is%20an). That's actually just a C-compatibility relic. So, if you want consistency, you totally can: [use `std::array`](https://godbolt.org/z/hKTe8v78r) although in a scenario *that* simple I'd [consider `initializer_list`](https://godbolt.org/z/o9z8MYfbW)

Comment: @sehe: `print(arr)` passes the `arr` but how the `size` gets calculated?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak It's deduced into `size_t size` by the compiler during overload resolution

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass the array by reference, you could

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
void print(const T(&array)[SIZE])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

and then, e.g.

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
print(x);
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/5GwGOn)

Otherwise, you can pass it by pointer, note that the array will decay to pointer, and you have to guarantee the correctness of `SIZE` being passed.

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T array[], size_t SIZE)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

and then, e.g.

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
print(x, sizeof(x) / sizeof(int));
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/KrHSBq)

Comment: Note that passing (pointer+size) is a bit of an anti-pattern in C++. GSL defines `array_view` for precisely this reason