# Result of sizeof for C++ arrays and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, internal-representation, abstract-machine

On an x86_64 architecture, a pointer is 8 bytes. It makes sense to me that `sizeof(x)` should return 8. I understand that a `char` is a single byte, and 5 bytes is the size of array `z`. What is the intuition behind why `sizeof(z)` does not return 8?

```cpp
int* x = new int[10];
char z[5];

// Returns 8
std::cout << "This is the size of x: " << sizeof(x) << std::endl;

// Returns 5
std::cout << "This is the size of z: " << sizeof(z) << std::endl;
```

Comment: `z` is an array of 5 char.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.  So the array of 5 chars doesn't degrade to a pointer when passed to `sizeof`.  Or in other words, when an array is passed to `sizeof`, the result is the absolute size of the array in bytes.

Comment: The size of z is 5 bytes, not 8 or 16 or 777. What other intuition could be there?

Comment: Do you know that you can write template functions that keep the size of an array? [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234979/how-to-write-a-template-function-that-takes-an-array-and-an-int-specifying-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the intuition behind why `sizeof(z)` does not return 8?

`z` is not a pointer. Hence `sizeof(z)` is not anything, but 5 bytes. In case of `sizeof`, the array doesn't decay to pointer. Refer: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

---

There are several implicit conversions in C++ like array to pointer, enum to integer, `double` to `float`, derived to base, any pointer to `void*` and so on. Which may lead us to think if their sizes are same or what?
Hence, a litmus test for self understanding is to create a pointer reference & try to assign the other type. It results in error for non matching types. e.g.

```
int *x = new int[5], *&px = x; // OK
int z[5], *&pz = z; // error: can't initialize
```

Comment: Is it not the case that an array is a pointer to its first element?

Comment: @Tantillo, no, it is not the case that an array is a pointer to it's first element. In most cases, such as when indexing or passing to a function, the array is implicitly converted to a pointer, but that does not mean that's what it actually is.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `x` as a pointer to char, so `sizeof(x)` yields the size of a pointer to char. On a current implementation, that'll typically be either 32 bits or 64 bits. A `char` is typically 8 bits, so you can expect `sizeof(char *)` to yield 4 or 8 on most current compilers.

You've defined `z` as an array of 5 char, so `sizeof(z)` yields the size of an array of 5 char. Since the elements of an array are contiguous, and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, the obvious value for that would be 5.

If (for example) you put an array of 5 char into a struct, and that's followed by (say) an `int`, there's a very good chance the compiler will insert some padding between those two elements.

Comment: In the case of an array inside a struct/class, any compiler-added padding is not part of the array itself, it follows the array, so calling `sizeof` for the array will not include the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Every character have size of '1'
Suppose when you compile it

```
 //It returns 1
      char z='a';
     std::cout << "This is the size of z: " << sizeof(z) << std::endl;
//It returns 5 because it is an array of 5 characters
 char z[5];
std::cout << "This is the size of z: " << sizeof(z) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Here is one more point check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an **array name** to sizeof, you want to know how many "bytes" of data belong to this array.

When you pass a **pointer** to sizeof, you want to know how many "bytes" does this pointer occupy.

The difference is very obvious when you pass an array name as a function argument. In this case the function cannot see the whole data area the array occupies. It only see the "pointer" type.