# why we need template <int N> since we have class initialization

Tags: c++

recently I knew a new template usage like below

```
template <unsigned int N>
```

I saw the answer here
[What does template <unsigned int N> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499106/what-does-template-unsigned-int-n-mean#)
It showed several examples includes:

```
template<unsigned int S>
struct Vector {
    unsigned char bytes[S];
};
```

However, I cannot figure out the point of this usage.
Why don't we just use class initialization to do this work.
What's the point of using a template here?

Comment: Assume you tried to pass the size to a constructor. The compiler must parse the class definition before any constructor is called. What's the object size?

Comment: The "standard type" would be `std::array<char, S>` which is pretty much identical to this `vector<S>`. Calling this `Vector` might suggest a similarity to `std::vector<char>`. And that's precisely the relevant difference: compile-time versus run-time sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a class must be known at compile-time. So you can't provide the size at class initialization time. This includes the size of any fixed-sized arrays included in the class.

To confuse matters there are some compiler extensions that allow you to use the syntax of fixed-size arrays with dynamically allocated size but this is not standard C++.

Even classes like `std::vector` have a fixed size but they use dynamic memory allocation for their contents so the size of the contents can be provided at class initialization time. Such containers contain a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory instead of a fixed-size array.

Comment: *"To confuse matters there are some compiler extensions that allow you to use the syntax of fixed-size arrays with dynamically allocated size"* - Not as class members however, if memory serves.

Comment: @StoryTeller: IIRC, one common extension is to support VLA's as the _last_ member of a class.

Comment: @MSalters - You mean flexible array members? Those must be last and aren't accounted for in the types size as returned by sizeof. They are standard C99, but I am not aware of a compiler that offers such an extension for C++.